# Any statement similar to "when" - javascript

Tags: javascript

Do you know a way to be constantly checking something? I am using a plugin of ".scollto" and I want to perform a function when the plugin which has scrolled reaches its destiny. So I thought there may be a statement like "when" or something, like

> "when" ($(window).scrolltop() == destiny) { //do something}

If I use IF/ELSE statements, it will check in the moment the code is read, but i want to check it once a while the plugin scrolls, or constantly. I don't care, but I want to get the action.

maybe it could be

```
scroll();
setTimeout(check(), 2000);
```

What do you think? does anyone know anything similar? Thank you.

Comment: Change the code to raise an event.

Comment: Javascript is event-driven. Look for events that the `scrollTo` plugin fires, or fire your own.

Comment: thank you, i will try to fire an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing built-in that does this.

Usually you write a handler for whatever event might change the state that you're interested in. Every time the event fires, your handler checks for the condition being met. For instance, using the scrollbar triggers the `scroll` event.

If there's no such event, you can use `setInterval` to run a function periodically, and it can check for the condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want other things to be going on while the checking is going on? If not, you could simply use a loop.
Otherwise, look up what an instance is.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a function to the window.onscroll() handler.

make the first line of the function check to see where it's scrolled.

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
   if ($(window).scrolltop() == destiny) { //do something
   }
}
```

everytime the window scrolls it will call that function.

Comment: thank you, but I mean mouse wheel not scrollbar, and I may have to use and event for that, thanks anyway

Comment: I don't understand the distinction. This will fire if the scroll position of the window changes regardless of why it changes. If you use arrows, mousewheel or the scrollbar itself.